# Can Cortana do text to speech on mobile apps?

Tags: java, android, ios, unity-game-engine, cortana

I am developing a game using unity, and will be generate to iOS / android version for playing, can some one tell me the text to speech function can run on it ? Because I can not find the supporting doucument about that, thanks!

Comment: I think you have to implement text to speech dependingly on the platform. Cortana is specifically for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Cortana for text to speech functionality as of now. You will have to use a Cortana alternative like Braina for that. After installing Braina, Press Ctrl+Alt+A to enable "Autoread Copied Text" feature.  Now you can copy any text  that you want Braina to read it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not Cortona but for Text to Speech you can refer below links

Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html

iOS: https://github.com/marceloqueiroz/GoogleTTSAPI